# NIFI Duplicate Duplicate Record Flag

Tags: apache-nifi

My requirement is simple, but not able to figure out solution for this.

I need to check contents for the file, if it's having duplicate rows then mark attribute Yes else no.

Lets say I have attribute as ContentDup then it should be either Yes or No, without changing flowfile content.

Solutions I have came across are based on duplicate it will be route duplicate and non duplicate records. I don't want to create new flowfile, just want to this flag.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [DeduplicateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.DeduplicateRecord/) processor block which can evaluate rows for duplicates based on specific field values within a given row. Although it splits out values in the file between the `duplicate` and `non-duplicate` relationship, you can use the `duplicate relationship to determine if there were any duplicates matching your conditions and then add a flowfile attribute on the outgoing` original` relationship.